# Choosing between the SVM and the MLP classifier

Tags: neural-network, classification, svm, libsvm, knime

I have to train a classifier that would be able to discern 6 possible classes of the input samples. I also have a *Cost Matrix* to estimate the classifier's performance with and without considering the reject option.

So far, using the *Cross-validation* (*leave-one-out*), I split the dataset in training set and validation set, so I can measure the classifier's performance. I've reached these results in terms of **accuracy**:

- **MultiLayer Perceptron**: 57,69% without the reject option, 48,26% with the reject option
- **Support Vector Machine**: 61,99% without the reject option, 35,09% with the reject option

While in terms of **costs** (these are estimates obtained using the *Minimum Risk Classification* rule):

- **MLP**: 2,0028 without the reject option, 1,4965 with the reject option
- **SVM**: 1,6089 without the reject option, 0,8502 with the reject option

So I've reached a point where I don't know which classifier is better.

Of course the SVM has ridiculous low costs, but when you consider the reject option you suddenly notice that its accuracy is pretty bad (-13% lower than MLP).

In terms of **accuracy**, I'd say that the MLP is *better* than the SVM because of its average accuracy (considering both with/without the reject option): 52,97% (MLP) vs 48,54% (SVM).

But the SVM is *better* in terms of average cost: 1,74965 (MLP) vs 1,22955 (SVM).

Are there any guide lines to facilitate this decision?

**Edit (more information as requested):** the dataset has ~700 samples with ~1250 features. However with the Feature Selection I reduced the features to 81.

The test set (which I don't have) will be of ~700 samples.

Comment: There aren't any general rules. SVM's probably better than a simple MLP but then it all depends on the MLP's architecture, training algorithm and on your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is MLP implementation you're using. In general for very large inputs SVM surely will have better performance while MLP might be useless. depending on implementation, number of neurons etc an MLP might also get over-trained resulting in worse accuracy.

so you have to determine typical size of input first.

Comment: The dataset has ~700 samples with ~1250 features. Using the cross-validation (leave-one-out) I split the dataset in training set and validation set. However with the Feature Selection I reduced the features to 81. The test set (which I don't have) has ~700 samples.